# DirectX SDK Setup is freezing

Tags: windows, setup, directx, sdk

On my windows XP machine when I try to install the DirectX SDK the setup freezes on the first screen.

When I click on the "next" button the system does some processing and stays on the same window. Clicking again on the next button does nothing.

The directX SDK log only contains a single entry for each try:
12/01/09 09:49:03: DXSDKSetup: CLR version number = 2.0.50727

any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of DirectX are you installing? Know that DirectX 10 and onwards do not work in windows XP

Comment: Is not directx, it is the SDK. Anyway it is the latest version August 2009, that includes also 9, 10 and 11 preview SDKs.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning off System Restore. I just had the same problem yesterday and turning it off fixed it right away. (Although this was with Windows 7.)

Comment: Worked for me! Had the same problem with DX SDK June 2010 on Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything insightful in the install log?

```
%WINDIR%\Logs\DirectX_SDK.log
```

Specifically look for any error message or error codes that might help debug the problem.  Consider editing your original question with any new information.